# Displaying image on a Panel

Tags: c#, .net, panel, image

this i a snippet of my code....

```
 public void btn_browse_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                scan.Enabled = true;
                pic = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                pic2 = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);                                   

                pic = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                pic2 = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

                pictureBox1.Image = pic;
                pictureBox2.Image = pic2;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                textBox1.Text = open.FileName;
                pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;



            } // end of if opendialog


        } // end of try

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed loading image");
        }


    }
```

The question is: Am i able to display my image browsed on a Panel instead of a PictureBox ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could set the BackGroundImage of the panel to the image.

`panel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Basically **`PictureBox`** is made **to display images** while **`Panel`** is **for drawing** in it(curves, lines, rectangles,....)

So I suggest better to use pictureBox, but if you want to show image in panel.

1. You can draw it `on paint` event
   **OR**
2. Use `BackgroundImage` property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The [Panel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) has a member called `BackImageUrl`.  Just specify the URL of the picture you want to use as the background.

Answer (score 1):

For winforms, you can use the [BackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx) and [BackgroundImageLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout.aspx) properties of the Panel.